# How to add the value of items I checked in the ListView CheckBox

Tags: vb.net

I'm doing a school project, and caught myself stuck in this situation for how many days now. I can't find a way to add the values of the checked items in the ListView.

I found a way to add them all without checking the CheckBox, but I'm looking for a way to add them if I checked the items in the CheckBox.

```
Module PaymentControllerModule
    Public Sub TotalFeeValue()
        Dim query As String = "SELECT * FROM tbl_fees"
        Dim totalfees As Double

        Dim adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
        Dim command As New MySqlCommand
        Dim table As New DataTable
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim o As Integer

        With command
            .CommandText = query
            .Connection = databaseconnect
        End With

        With adapter
            .SelectCommand = command
            .Fill(table)
        End With

        formPaymentsDynamic.Lv_Paymentfees.Items.Clear()

        For i = 0 To table.Rows.Count - 1
            With formPaymentsDynamic.Lv_Paymentfees
                .Items.Add(table.Rows(i)("fee_description"))
                With .Items(.Items.Count - 1).SubItems
                    .Add(table.Rows(i)("fee_price"))
                End With
            End With

            totalfees += Val(table.Rows(i)("fee_price"))
            formPaymentsDynamic.txtTotalAmount.Text = totalfees
        Next
    End Sub
End Module
```

I expected the output of the summed items that were checked in the ListView, but I can only do the summed value of all the items even without checking them. I hope you can help me.

This is the sample output of the program, I manage to add the value in the ListView even it is not checked.

[image: Form]

Comment: What is the controller with the checkbox: datagridview, listview...?

Comment: @CodePope LV probably means ListView.

Comment: listview sir @CodePope

Comment: @LarsTech Lv_Paymentfees is the controller where he writes the results into. I was asking about the controller where he wants to read the data from

Comment: A ListView item has a Checked property.  The question isn't very clear where you need help.

Comment: I need help in adding all sum if I checked an item in the list view sir @LarsTech. I attached a photo in my post where I add all the sum even if I didnt checked it.

Comment: I can only do the sum of all the item in the listview, I dont know how to add it if I do some checkings already. hehe still a beginner here.

Comment: Loop through your items and if the item is checked (ListView.Items(x).Checked), add it to the sum.

Comment: okay sir @LarsTech I'll try to do that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to loop over the checked items in the `Listview` and not the Datatable. Your code could look similar to that:

```
For Each item As ListViewItem In YourListView.CheckedItems
    totalfees  += CDbl( item.SubItems("fee_price").Text)
Next
```

Comment: Thank you sir @Code Pope. I'll try to do that.

Comment: If something is unclear, let me know. Otherwise mark this as answer if it solved your question.

Comment: I have a question sir, if I'll do this way, how will I get the value of the checked item. because in the datatable, thats where I'm getting the value of each item in the listview?

Comment: When you are filling the Sourcelistview insert all data of the data table you need later as subitems in the listview. Later you can get each property by calling `item.SubItem("YourPropertyName").Text`